# Matching with SURF(Conceptual)

Tags: image-processing, surf

I am using surf to match n images together. finding fundamental matric by  to remove outliers in matching stage. Surprisingly i am finding fundamental matrix even though matching points are totally wrong. My question is what criteria or statics i should use to avoid such problem.
regards,

Comment: An example of your (wrong) results could help with the diagnosis ...

Answer (score 0):

An example of your code, or a detailed explanation of what you require might help us to show you a path.

If what you meant is that, even after matching two same images, the points being matched are wrong, then their is a chance for error in the calculation of descriptors. At least a sample output of the error you get would help us a lot. Are the keypoints are being detected correctly? Or is it just that the matching is going wrong?